# Installing a production and test version of an app on one device

Tags: android, android-build

I'm developing an app named `myApp` in Android. After completing some important functions I want to keep a build of this version on the device for testing while I continue developing.  I renamed *myApp* into *myAppTesting*, but android devices understand both to be the same app.

Can you guys help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should rename your main package.

In Eclipse:

Package Explorer > Right Click on project > Android Tools > Rename Android Package

Comment: Note that this will require you to rename the package _every_ time you want to switch between `release` and `dev`, and this is a costly operation which might fail sometimes.

Answer (score 13):

Applications are identified by their package name.

Give you test app a different package, like `com.myapp.dev`.

In Android Studio, you can achieve this by adding the following in your app's `build.gradle`:

```
android {
     /* More stuff */

     buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix = ".dev"
        }
    }
}
```

This way, release builds will have the original `com.myapp` package, while any debug build will have the `com.myapp.dev` package, allowing you to keep them both installed.